# Sharepoint 2013 List view filter column by [Me] not working all the time

Tags: listview, sharepoint, filtering, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-list

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2013 with some views. One of them is called "My tasks as manager". What happens is that when an user submits the new form, he or she can type in the manager's name for the task. So i set up the view to only show items when the column **Manager** equals [Me]. Sometimes it works ans sometimes i doesn't. Take me for example, I have 12 tasks assigned to me when I enter the default view, without filters. But in the view "My tasks as manager", I see 10 tasks/items for example. Sometimes, the filter doesn't show all the tasks that it should. I also have another custom field **Administrator**, and the filtering works like a charm here. Worth mentioning is that my new form is a customized application page which creates a list item and sets the column values after submit. Fine if the view didn't show any of the items, but it show some of them. Anyone have a clue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the User Profile causing the issue in filtering.

   Go to **Central Administration** => **Application Management** => **Manage service application** => **Manage User Profiles** => **Delete** after selecting the profile of User.
2. Remove User from Site Collection.
3. Logout and login again and then filter again and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

This is known bug.  You can find information about the at the link below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/53a7840c-5ffe-499e-933c-e93898beee54/sharepoint-server-2013-tasks-views-calendar-views-filtering-problem?forum=sharepointgeneral

You may try filtering using visual webpart with below query suggested in post.

```
string query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="<FieldName>" /><Value Type="Text">"+ SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name +"<Value></Eq></Where>";
```